# Is "Civic Virtue" related to moral in this context?

Tags: meaning, terminology

I came across this phrase:

"While no relationship was found between altruism and intention to leave both the organization and the current job, sportsmanship, ***civic virtue*** and helping others emerged as the strongest predictors of intention to leave the organization and intention to leave the current job."

According to Wikipedia: Civic virtue is the cultivation of habits of personal living that are claimed to be important for the success of the community

As I am translating this term into my native language, the question appears is:

1. Is Civic Virtue related to moral of society?
2. What is the best definition?

Any idea will be appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

"Civic virtue" means actions that make it possible for people to live together in a community and for society to function. Usually "civic virtues" are understood as duties to the government or to "society" as an abstract concept. Specifically it means things like obeying traffic laws, voting, being willing to serve on a jury, that sort of thing.

These things could be considered "morals", but civic virtue isn't really about the things we usually think of when we talk about "morality", like being faithful to your spouse or not using vulgar language. I suppose things like refraining from stealing or killing people are necessary to the functioning of society, but those aren't what people normally mean when they talk about civic virtues.

Answer (score 1):

I think this context 'civic duty' means contributing to the life of the organisation as a citizen would contribute to society.

Answer (score 1):

**Civic virtue**

is the cultivation of habits of personal living that are claimed to be important **for the success of the community**. The identification of the character traits that constitute civic virtue have been a major concern of political philosophy. **The term civility refers to behavior between persons and groups that conforms to a social mode (that is, in accordance with the civil society), as itself being a foundational principle of society and law.**
[Civic virtue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Civic_virtue)

I think that, as expressed in the above description, *civic virtue* implies a set of written and not written rules (including common moral standards) to which all people within a specific society in a specific historical moment must conform to  tha sake of the group or society they belong to.

So, yes moral standard are or can be part of a civic sense of a community. Another definition for it could be **respect for a set of shared values and rules.**

Comment: Can I go with "moral of society" ?

Answer (score 0):

Civic virtue is a subset of Morals.

Comment: Any support for your opinion? And do you really consider it *immoral* (as opposed to dangerous or illegal) to break the speed limit?